# Let $Q$ be the set of all $x \in H$ of the form $x = \sum_1^{\infty} c_n u_n$ for $|c_n| \le \frac 1n$. Show that $Q$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

This is Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Problem 4.6.
Let $Q$ be the set of all $x \in H$ of the form $x = \sum_1^{\infty} c_n u_n$ for $|c_n| \le \frac 1n$. Show that $Q$ is compact.

Assume I have a sequence $\{x^k\}$ in which we have $x^k, x^l$ such that

> $\|x^k - x^l \|^2 = \sum |c_n^k - c_n^l|^2$

Then I was only able to bound the distance between $x^k, x^l$ with $\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{6}}$, a term coming from the $1/n$.

But given arbitrary $\epsilon$, I'm having some troubling finding the subsequence that can lower the  difference between the coefficients. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: What is $H$? What is $u_n$?

Comment: $H$ is a Hilbert space, $u_n$ is an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is clearly a closed subset of $H$. Therefore, and since $H$ is complete, your set is complete. Now, prove that it is totally bounded too and you're done.